# How to save values from matrix to another with keeping columns and rows names unchanged in R?

Tags: arrays, r, sorting, matrix, indexing

I have a correlation matrix `data.corr` which consists of 163 companies, therefore the matrix dimensions are 163 rows and 163 columns.

I want to sort the highest 5 correlation values of each companny, so I wrote the following code:

```
COR<- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 163)
for(i in 1:163){COR[,i]<-tail(sort(data.corr[i,]),5)}
```

It works well, but the problem that it doesn't copy the rows and columns name from the original correlation matrix for each value.

the row and column names are the company names.
here is a sample of the correlation matrix:

```
    head(data.corr)
X601288.SS X601988.SS X601998.SS X601818.SS X601939.SS X601398.SS
X601288.SS  1.0000000  0.7628263  0.6130694  0.7947062  0.7578003  0.7568238
X601988.SS  0.7628263  1.0000000  0.7280957  0.6925497  0.8402101  0.8409767
X601998.SS  0.6130694  0.7280957  1.0000000  0.6715793  0.7118446  0.6716997
X601818.SS  0.7947062  0.6925497  0.6715793  1.0000000  0.6825405  0.6471228
X601939.SS  0.7578003  0.8402101  0.7118446  0.6825405  1.0000000  0.8390544
X601398.SS  0.7568238  0.8409767  0.6716997  0.6471228  0.8390544  1.0000000
```

here a sample of the highest five correlations:

```
head(COR)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
[1,] 0.7568238 0.7280957 0.6894561 0.6715793 0.7558052 0.7323083 0.7323083 0.6894561
[2,] 0.7578003 0.7628263 0.7118446 0.6825405 0.7578003 0.7568238 0.7472125 0.6956420
[3,] 0.7628263 0.8402101 0.7223088 0.6925497 0.8390544 0.8390544 0.7558052 0.7007705
[4,] 0.7947062 0.8409767 0.7280957 0.7947062 0.8402101 0.8409767 0.7618053 0.7618053
[5,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

any ideas how to sort the values with their matching column and row names?

Comment: Are the row/column names the company names? If so, won't the names of the 5 columns in your `COR` matrix need to be different for each row? If the row/col names are just indices, can you just renumber them afterwards? Posting some sample data and a better explanation of what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: yes the row/column names are the company names. and yes the names in `COR` should match the names of the values in `data.corr`. I have edited the question and posted samples .

Comment: What would the row/column names be in your example? I assume row names are just 1...5 and the col names are the company names? Or do the row names also need to be company names?

Comment: If the company names are in the same order, you can just do `colnames(COR) <- colnames(data.corr)`.

Comment: they are not at the same order, it is something that I had to pay attention for when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should simplify your code and work for you:

```
# Toy data
data.corr <- cor(matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10))
rownames(data.corr) <- colnames(data.corr) <- paste0("company", 1:10)
print(data.corr)

# Get highest correlations for each company
COR <- apply(data.corr, 2, sort, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5 + 1, ]

# Get corresponding rows / companies
COR_comp <- apply(data.corr, 2, order, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5 + 1, ]
```

If you insist that it is the names that appear (and not numbers) that appear in `COR_comp`, you can modify it further. For example, the following will fill in the company names:

```
COR_comp[]  <- colnames(COR_comp )[c(COR_comp )]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `data.table` and `dplyr`

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
# example data
data <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 20) %>% data.frame
data.corr <- cor(data)

melted_data <- data.corr %>% 
  data.frame %>% # convert to a data.frame
  mutate(row_company = row.names(.)) %>% # create a new variable from col.name
  melt(id.vars = "row_company") # change the data shape from wide to long
setDT(melted_data) # crate a data.table

# sort the data first by compnay and decending order of the correlation)
# when select top 5 in each company
final_output <- melted_data[order(variable, -value)][, head(.SD, 5), by=variable]
head(final_output, 10)
```

Comment: I applied it but it gives me the correlation of everything not only the highest correlations

Comment: You need to create a new data.table from the output. I modified my answer.